# Making the enemy die when hit with a bullet

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript game, and I can't make the enemy die when hit with a bullet. Here is the part of the code that I just can't understand:

```
    for(var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++){
    ctx.fillRect(enemies[i].x,enemies[i].y,30,100);

    if(player.x+player.width>enemies[i].x && player.x<enemies[i].x+30 && player.y+player.height>enemies[i].y && player.y<enemies[i].y+100){
        document.location.reload();
    }


}

for (var b=0;b<bullets.length;b++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bullets[b].x,bullets[b].y,2,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();     
    bullets[b].x += bullets[b].dx;

    if(bullets[b].x>enemies[i].x && bullets[b].x<enemies[i].x+enemies[i].width && bullets[b].y>enemies[i].y && bullets[b].y<enemies[i].y+enemies[i].height){
        enemies.splice(i,1);
    }   

}
```

So, I know that the problem is that it can't read the property "x" of enemies[i] because I didn't put it in the enemies for loop, but if i put it there then it can't read the property "x" of bullets[b]. I've been stuck on this for two days now and searched everything I could find, but didn't find anything useful at all. I would appreciate any help...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need nested loops here

Comment: Yea I tried that but when the enemy disappears I can't shoot any more bullets...

Comment: @Vuxer Then *that* is your real problem. You need to check every bullet against every enemy, and  (absent a better data structure and algorithm for collision detection) a nested for loop is the way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to check all the ennemies, for each bullet.

This is done using *nested loops*:

```
for (var b=0;b<bullets.length;b++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bullets[b].x,bullets[b].y,2,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();     
    bullets[b].x += bullets[b].dx;
    for (var j=ennemies.length; j-- >0;) {
        if(bullets[b].x>enemies[j].x && bullets[b].x<enemies[j].x+enemies[j].width && bullets[b].y>enemies[j].y && bullets[b].y<enemies[j].y+enemies[j].height){
            enemies.splice(j,1);
        }  
    }
}
```

Note: In this example I loop over enemies in reverse order in order to avoid missing an ennemy when splicing.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this the enemy is visible only while I'm shooting bullets...

Comment: @Vuxer This is a totally different problem. BTW it's usually easier to manage such a code when you separate the functions updating the data (including checking collisions) and the functions rendering the data (drawing)